# Iterate through a List property of an object with Struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

Considering the following:

```
public class Company {
    private String name;
    private List<Person> employees;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Car> cars;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Car {
    private String color;

    //getter and setter
}
```

I want to get with Struts2 the **color** property of every car for every employee. So how would I iterate over the list of cars of every employee of the Company object?

After creating it, I put employees as **employeeList** into session. Using the following method, I can only get the **name** property, but can't iterate over the **cars** property:

```xml
<s:if test="#session.employeeList.size() > 0">
    <s:iterator value="#session.employeeList">
        <s:property value="name" /> //this works
        <s:property value="cars" /> //how do I iterate over this list?
    </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

Doing this, the output for "cars" property is `ognl.NoConversionPossible`

I tried something like:

```xml
<s:if test="#session.employeeList.size() > 0">
    <s:iterator value="#session.employeeList">
        <s:property value="name" /> //this works
        <s:iterator value="cars">
            <s:property value="color" />
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

but doesn't work that way. Any ideas?

LE: Solution: Actually the iteration works. The objects I was talking about are mapped as Hibernate Entities. The "List cars" property is in fact a `@ManyToMany` relationship. So, after looking deeper into the error logs I found out that the cars property that I was trying to iterate was not being populated because Hibernate was lazily initializing it by default. I changed the `FetchType` to `EAGER` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

> The fact that I use session over the action attributes is not really important. Though, **how could I use action attributes in this case? It doesn't seem doable**.

Why not ?

**Action**:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private Company company;         // private attribute
    public Company getCompany(){     // public getter
        return company; 
    }

    public String execute(){
        company = someService.loadTheCompanySomehow();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**JSP**:

```xml
<s:iterator value="company.employees">
    <s:property value="name" />
    <s:iterator value="cars">
        <s:property value="color" />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

If the inner iteration doesn't work, there is probably something you have not shown to us, or related to the way you've cleaned the code before posting it.

Comment: Same problem occured using action attribute instead of session. But you're right, I omitted some details. The objects I was talking about are mapped as Hibernate Entities. The "List<Car> cars" property is in fact a @ManyToMany relationship. So, after looking deeper into the error logs I found out that the cars property that I was trying to iterate was not being populated because Hibernate was lazily initializing it by default. I changed the FetchType to EAGER and the problem was solved.